# provide application update only for iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have an app in App store which supports iPhone & iPad. 
Now I want to update the app only for iPhone and I do not want to support iPad.

Is it possible?

If I'm posting this question in the wrong forum, please let me know the correct forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that,  you will be get an error in time of uploading the app, what you can do now is hide your existing app from all territory and upload your app with a new bundle id with supported device iphone, in this case the user never get the update notification for your existing live app, it will be a new app.

Thanks.